# How do I get pytest to ignore a specific subprocess call that returns non-zero code and writes to stderr?

Tags: python, pytest, stderr

My code (within pytest) is:

```
    try:
        proc = subprocess.check_output(['somedaemon', '-v'], stderr=subprocess.STDERR)
        assert str(proc) is False, 'somedaemon returned a version number, should be uninstalled'
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        # There was an error - command exited with non-zero code                                                                                                                            
        pass
```

My desire here is that a *passing* test has the subprocess call to somedaemon return a non-zero return code and output on stderr and still pass.   I can't seem to get pytest to ignore the error in this case.
In other words a try without except is a failure.   Failure of the subprocess is expected.

Pytest's more global error catching is defeating me and I haven't 
found a way of overriding it.

OS is CentOS 7.

After applying Branden's solution below, I got the following result (these are snippets from pytest's error reporting):

A. here is a pdb next through the subprocess call:

-> proc = subprocess.Popen(['cbdaemon', '-v'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(Pdb) n
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cbdaemon'

B. in the error report, we are entering subprocess.py:

/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py:707: in **init**
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

C. subprocess.py has a raise child_exception_type that raises the error:

```
            if errno_num != 0:
                err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
                if errno_num == errno.ENOENT:
                    if child_exec_never_called:
                        # The error must be from chdir(cwd).
                        err_msg += ': ' + repr(cwd)
                    else:
                        err_msg += ': ' + repr(orig_executable)
```

> ```
>           raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
> ```
>
> E               FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cbdaemon'

/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py:1326: FileNotFoundError

This might be an intractable problem.    I looked through a lot of pytest documents and can't find a way to exclude this failure from the overall test failure.   The error is coded into subprocess.py.

Comment: why not just `assert False` ? note that `check_output` won't capture the output if the process exits with an error. You need `Popen` or if pyhton 3.5 `subprocess.run`, properly configured.

Comment: I think you are misconstruing the question: the problem is that I expect the subprocess to fail and I don't know how to get pytest to ignore that error.

Comment: no, I perfectly understood your question. Brendan answer seem to fit, and it's using `Popen`, as I had advised.

Comment: subprocess triggers: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'somedaemon' and the test fails under pytest.   I want it to pass.

Comment: that's not the same issue. Your process doesn't return a non-zero value, your process cannot be _launched_ because not in the path, or something like this.

Comment: Jean-Francois, I apologize, testing Brendan's answer now.

Comment: no need to apologize. Note that it's normal that the test fails: the process isn't run.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `Popen` for this and assert the return code and error message.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['somedaemon', '-v'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
assert proc.returncode and err
```

Comment: This errors when the subprrocess errors, right?   I want pytest to ignore errors when this subprocess executes.    If the subprocess returns 0, I will assert an error.

Comment: @J.Curtis No, this errors when the subprocess returns either a `0` exit code or doesn't print anything to `stderr`.  So it only passes when the process both returns a non-zero exit code *and* prints something to stderr

Comment: Brendan, I agree that your code does that, just tested it.   Unfortunately, the subprocess.py errors in a way that I  don't know how to suppress.  Thanks for your help.   See my addition to the question above.

Comment: @J.Curtis The subprocess call is erroring because it can't find the cbdaemon executable.  That's a separate error.  Do you want your test to pass if you get that exception?  I wouldn't think so.